# editable div dont duplicate image (or its code) on input JQuery

Tags: jquery, keyup

I'm creating an EmojiPicker for my website, but I'm having problems with passing the editable div data to an input to validate it later in a form.

The problem is that the emojis pastes in the `div` but not in the `input`, because I'm using `keyUp` and the code doesnt recognize it the paste, so I have no way to save them (or a textual code of them) in my database.

For example if an user writes: `" Hi everyone --1--, how is everythin going"` I would like it to be duplicated like that in the `input` so that once Its retrieved from the database, the `--1--` be replaced by a happy fac image. But while the user is writing the post the `--1--` code be shown in the `div` as the happy face for a best user experience.

I have this fiddle but is not working properly

https://jsfiddle.net/r5o2zv7x/15/

https://jsfiddle.net/b6c7mz42/29/

```js
$(".emoticon").click(function(){
    var div_val = jQuery.trim($("#myPost").html());
    var emoticon_val = $(this).attr("value");
    
    
    if(emoticon_val=="--1--"){emoticon_vale="<img src='https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/styles/news_article_hero/public/news_article_images/emoji.jpg?itok=kew_ndmU' height=18 />";}
    
    if(emoticon_val=="--2--"){emoticon_vale="<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrtesx1eLvxrO27WYYBvmUKpJufAjyw-9bKIhSH0_C5ntqmLSh'  height=18 />";}

  //show in div
    $("#myPost").focus().html(div_val + '&nbsp;' + emoticon_vale + '&nbsp;');
     $('#copytoInput').val( $('#copytoInput').val() + emoticon_val);
  });
                               
$('#myPost').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
             $('#copytoInput').val($(this).text());
                                    });
```

```css
#myPost{
margin:10px 0;
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#copytoInput{

margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='emoji_picker'>
  <input type=image value='--1--' src='https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/styles/news_article_hero/public/news_article_images/emoji.jpg?itok=kew_ndmU' height=18 class=emoticon />
  <input type=image value='--2--' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrtesx1eLvxrO27WYYBvmUKpJufAjyw-9bKIhSH0_C5ntqmLSh' height=18 class=emoticon />

</div>

  <div contentEditable="true" id='myPost'></div>
                  <input  type=text id=copytoInput >
```

Comment: Are these real HTML entities or just images?

Comment: images. Do you know how to solve this? this is important for my site.

Comment: I have no idea, that's why I asked about HTML entities and images. I see you have PNGs but I had to be sure that your emojis are just images. The contenteditable part I'm not sure as to why you chose that if you are just having users upload emoji's?

Comment: No, the emojis are already on the server. The users just pick one to use in their post. This is why this is a EmojisPicker?

Comment: Data: 5 images / UI: `<select>` tag. Why do you need to validate images? Why do you need a contenteditable tag for the users?

Comment: The point is to save each image represented with a code, in order those codes to be easily replaced by the same image once they are outputed.

Comment: That's what a variable is for.

Comment: I know, it doesnt help at all. I need help with duplicating the div into the input....this is the help I need

Comment: Go **[here](https://websemantics.uk/tools/image-to-data-uri-converter/)** to convert your images to data URI. It'll be huge but it'll render in a browser as an image and be accepted as encoded text.

Comment: Ok thank you. I would kindly ask you to try my code, its fuctional, you are going to realise that there is no way to pass the image to the input or its data code. It passes the texts only. This is the problem because the code duplicates the keyUp entries in the div, not the click events like the used to paste the images in the div, for this reason it doesnt recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

> if an user writes: " Hi everyone --1--, how is everythin going" I
>   would like it to be duplicated like that in the input

according to above statement this snippet copies value of div to input on change.value of emoji's will be coded as you said. if it is not answer you need ,let me know

```js
$(".emoticon").click(function(){
    var div_val = jQuery.trim($("#myPost").html());
    var emoticon_val = $(this).val();


   
  //show in div
    $("#myPost").focus().html(div_val + '&nbsp;<img src=' + $(this).attr('src') + '>&nbsp;');


                               });

$('#myPost').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
var txt=$(this).html();

var chil=$(this).children();
txt=txt.replace('<img src="http://smashersblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/img-thing-300x300.jpg">','--3--');
txt=txt.replace('<img src="http://bsmedia.business-standard.com/_media/bs/img/article/2015-11/17/full/1447765386-257.jpg">','--2--');
txt=txt.replace('<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e2/30/c7/e230c7981926661d73caabc0d4fd6fd3--emoji-faces-smiley-faces.jpg">','--1--');
             $('#copytoInput').val(txt);
                                    });
```

```css
input[type=image],img{
height:20px;
width:20px;
}
div{
height:50px;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='emoji_picker'>
  <input type=image value='--1--' src='https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e2/30/c7/e230c7981926661d73caabc0d4fd6fd3--emoji-faces-smiley-faces.jpg' class=emoticon />
  <input type=image value='--2--' src='http://bsmedia.business-standard.com/_media/bs/img/article/2015-11/17/full/1447765386-257.jpg' class=emoticon />
  <input type=image value='--3--' src='http://smashersblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/img-thing-300x300.jpg' class=emoticon />
</div>

  <div contentEditable="true" id='myPost'></div>
                  <input  type=text id=copytoInput >
```

new:

```js
$(".emoticon").click(function(){
    var div_val = jQuery.trim($("#myPost").html());
    var emoticon_val = $(this).attr("value");
    
    
    if(emoticon_val=="--1--"){emoticon_vale="<img src='https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/styles/news_article_hero/public/news_article_images/emoji.jpg?itok=kew_ndmU' height=18 />";}
    
    if(emoticon_val=="--2--"){emoticon_vale="<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrtesx1eLvxrO27WYYBvmUKpJufAjyw-9bKIhSH0_C5ntqmLSh'  height=18 />";}

  //show in div
    $("#myPost").focus().html(div_val + '&nbsp;' + emoticon_vale + '&nbsp;');

  $('#copytoInput').val( $('#copytoInput').val() + emoticon_val);
  });
                               
$('#myPost').on('change keyup',function(){
             var i=$('#copytoInput').val();
             
                  $('#copytoInput').val( $(this).text()+i);
                  
                               console.log($(this).text())     });
```

```css
#myPost{
margin:10px 0;
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#copytoInput{

margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='emoji_picker'>
  <input type=image value='--1--' src='https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/styles/news_article_hero/public/news_article_images/emoji.jpg?itok=kew_ndmU' height=18 class=emoticon />
  <input type=image value='--2--' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrtesx1eLvxrO27WYYBvmUKpJufAjyw-9bKIhSH0_C5ntqmLSh' height=18 class=emoticon />

</div>

  <div contentEditable="true" id='myPost'></div>
                  <input  type=text id=copytoInput >
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. It passes now a code of every image to the input...it would be perfect if in the editable ´div´ would show the image not the code.

Comment: @Jean check out now

Comment: I see, it would be posible to replace `&nbsp;` by white space. you are pretty close! :)

Comment: @Jean check out now error was replacing replacing only with new entry

Comment: it's duplicating the same text on the input, last one was better

Comment: I think the replacement have to be using `.each()`